# De-reference x number of times for x number of data structures

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, dereference

I've come across an obstacle in one of my perl scripts that I've managed to solve, but I don't really understand why it works the way it works. I've been scouring the internet but I haven't found a proper explanation.

I have a subroutine that returns a reference to a hash of arrays. The hash keys are simple strings, and the values are references to arrays.

I print out the elements of the array associated with each key, like this

```
for my $job_name (keys %$build_numbers) {
    print "$job_name => ";
    my @array = @{@$build_numbers{$job_name}};  # line 3
    for my $item ( @array ) {
        print "$item \n";
    } 
}
```

While I am able to print out the keys & values, I don't really understand the syntax behind line 3.

Our data structure is as follows:

Reference to a hash whose values are references to the populated arrays.

To extract the elements of the array, we have to:
- dereference the hash reference so we can access the keys
- dereference the array reference associated to a key to extract elements.

Final question being:

- When dealing with perl hashes of hashes of arrays etc; to extract the elements at the "bottom" of the respective data structure "tree" we have to dereference each level in turn to reach the original data structures, until we obtain our desired level of elements?

Hopefully somebody could help out by clarifying.

Comment: I can't tell what the actual question is here, but the answer is to read [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Dereference from the hashref, `$build_numbers->{$job_name}`, then dereference that value since it's an arrayref, `@{$build_numbers->{$job_name}}`. You need curlies in `@{ ... }` for precedence rules.  The second `@` in your code is extra.  That's basics, there are many ways to work with these.  Yes, you need to go through levels to get to the bottom, how else? You should read the relevant docs, life will be much better afterwards.

Comment: Is this parsed content of some kind? You usually get complicated data structures when parsing XML or JSON or something.

Comment: You should start by dumping your data structure. `Data::Dumper` is okay, and is a core module, while `Data::Dump` is superior but may need installing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 3 is taking a [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) of your hash reference, but it's a very strange way to do what you're trying to do because a) you normally wouldn't slice a single element and b) there's cleaner and more obvious syntax that would make your code easier to read.

If your data looks something like this:

```
my $data = {
    foo => [0 .. 9],
    bar => ['A' .. 'F'],
};
```

Then the correct version of your example would be:

```
for my $key (keys(%$data)) {
    print "$key => ";

    for my $val (@{$data->{$key}}) {
        print "$val ";
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

Which produces:

```
bar => A B C D E F
foo => 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

If I understand your second question, the answer is that you can access precise locations of complex data structures if you use the correct syntax. For example:

```
print "$data->{bar}->[4]\n";
```

Will print `E`.

Additional recommended reading: [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: The reason I did it like that is because I didn't want to use the -> notation (as used in your and carlosns answer), but wanted to use a shorter/more readable version.

I thought that @$hash_ref{$job} is equivalent to @{$hash_ref->{$job}}. But if I use that notation, my print returns the hexa code for the array itself and not it's content. I then tried to add another @{} to deref it again and this time it seemed to print out the contents of the array.

Your format is actually clearer than the one that I found to work.

Answer (score 0):

Working with data structures can be hard depending on how it was made.

I am not sure if your "job" data structure is exactly this but:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;


my $hash_ref = {

 job_one => [ 'one', 'two'],
 job_two => [ '1','2'],

};

foreach my $job ( keys %{$hash_ref} ){

 print " Job => $job\n";

 my @array = @{$hash_ref->{$job}};

 foreach my $item ( @array )
 {

        print "Job: $job Item $item\n";
 }

}
```

You have an hash reference which you iterate the keys that are arrays. But each item of this array could be another reference or a simple scalar.

Basically you can work with the ref or undo the ref like you did in the first loop.

There is a piece of documentation you can check for more details [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

So answering your question:

> Final question being: - When dealing with perl hashes of hashes of
>   arrays etc; to extract the elements at the "bottom" of the respective
>   data structure "tree" we have to dereference each level in turn to
>   reach the original data structures, until we obtain our desired level
>   of elements?

It depends on how your data structure was made and if you already know what you are looking for it would be simple to get the value for example:

> %city_codes = (
>
> a => 1,  b => 2,
>
> );
>
> my $value = $city_codes{a};

Complex data structures comes with complex code.

Comment: I tried the syntax you suggested @{$hash_ref->{$job}} to create my array and it worked. While I've seen this syntax being used in the docs I used; I tried using the shorter version ie without the -> and my version also works. @{@$build_numbers{$job_name}}.

Comment: So It's all fine :-)